# getting a next html anchor/selector, relative to viewport / scroll position?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I have a multi-section HTML page.

There's a position:fixed  --> when clicked, it should jump (scroll) to next/nearest .

however, the next section is relative to viewport, not to the button (DOM).

Is there a simple / built-in way to define "segments" of HTML, so that it "knows" where's the next segment, and user can

my toolbox:  jquery, javascript, html/css, wordpress.

*EDIT*

Since starting this question I actually [wrote a jquery solution](https://codepen.io/berryts/pen/BayPxxB) :

```
enumerates sections => position (as Y)
on event:
    get current offset;
    compare offset against each pair of consequent Y's
        if match:
            jumps to (next-near) selector.
            break;
```

but that's error prone, and incomplete.

There's probably a better, native solution for "next viewport" or "paging", isn't it?

Comment: i've search here for similar questions, but couldn't find something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `prev` calculation is wrong as you did not handle condition where your `i` is 0. It should be look something like below:

```
function next() {
  console.log(ys);
  var here = $(document).scrollTop(), prev;
  console.log('here:', here);
  for(i=0;i<ys.length -1;i++){ 
    if (i == 0 ) {
      prev = 0;
    } else {
      prev = ys[i -1];
    }   console.log('here:',here,'prev:',prev,'curr:',ys[i],'next:',ys[i+1]);
    if (here>=prev && here<=ys[i]) {
      console.log('found', i, ys[i]);
      return ys[i];
    }
  } 
}
```